# having difficulty building a joined query across multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I'm currently trying to get my head around a MySQL query that I want to do. It could well be that I'm just not thinking clearly as I've not slept but I've been a bit stuck on this for a while.

I am trying to build a query to return all the attachments that a user on my site has access to. Every attachment has an `owner_id` associated with it and there are also groups that are linked to the `attachments` table via a `groups_attachments` table.

So my tables are:

```
+--------------------+
| attachments        |
| groups             |
| groups_attachments |
| users              |
| users_attachments  |
| users_groups       |
+--------------------+
```

attachments, groups, and users all have their own ids and the linking table holds the ids of each table being linked.

I want to select all fields from attachments if either the `attachment.owner_id` matches a `users.user_id` or if `users.user_id` is in the `users_attachments` (when an owner grants permission specifically)  or if `users.user_id` is in `users_groups` for a group that is related to an attachment via `users_attachments`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to do it all with one magic query - use a series of queries unioned together:

```
select *
from attachments
where owner_id = $userid
union
select a.*
from users_attachments ua
join attachments a on a.attachment_id = ua.attachment_id
where ua.user_id = $userid
union
select a.*
from users u
join groups_attachments ga on ga.group_id = u.group_id
join attachments a on a.attachment_id = ga.attachment_id
where users.user_id = $userid
```

Substitute `$userid` for the target user id (there are three places you must do this).

This query should perform pretty well. I have coded the tables selection order and joins carefully to give good performance.

You haven't said what your column names are, so I made reasonable guesses.

Comment: You sir are a genius! I only had to make a minor change to the third part to get it working.

Instead of "from users u" I needed "FROM users_groups ug" and to ammend the JOIN and WHERE as applicable